# Jquery for each input elements except focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which selector can I use to iterate through all input elements on the page *except* for the currently focused one?

This is what I currently have:

```js
total = 0.00;

$(".numbers").each(function() {
  total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="numbers" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't love initializing a variable outside of the loop itself, so I'd suggest `.toArray().reduce()`, personally.

```js
$("input:first").focus();   //for demo only

var total = $(".numbers:not(:focus)").toArray().reduce((sum, element) => sum + Number(element.value),0);
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="numbers" value="5" />
<input type="text" class="numbers" value="2" />
<input type="text" class="numbers" value="12" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".numbers:not(':focus')").each(function(){
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.numbers:not(:focus)').each(function(){

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".numbers:not(':focus')").each(function(index,element){
    total += parseFloat($(element).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way:

```
$.each($('.number').not(':focus'), function(idx, ele) {
    total += parseFloat(ele.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `:not(:focus)` is your anti-select you're looking for.  Also you may `$('.numbers').not(':focus')` to filter an existing set:

```js
function calculate() {
  let total = $(".numbers:not(:focus)").get().reduce((sum, el) =>
    (sum += parseFloat(+el.value), sum), 0);

  console.log('Sum:',total)
}

$('input').on('keydown', calculate)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Change the number of the textbox:</p>
<input class="numbers" value="1" />
<input class="numbers" value="2" />
<input class="numbers" value="3" />
<input class="numbers" value="4" />
```